# Angular 7+: Override service with an adapter for application submodule

Tags: angular

I have a basic view service that acts as a singleton across the application. One instance and it keeps the state of the views in sync. The interface is pretty simple:

```
items$: Observable<Item[]>;
add(item: Item): Promise<void>;
remove(id: string): Promise<void>;
load(id: string): Promise<ItemDetail>;
```

I want for a certain part of the application to create an adapter over this service that adds one new method:

```
beginTransaction(): {commit: () => Promise<void>, cancel: ()=>void; };
```

The idea is that once in a transaction, adding and removing items will add them to a pending list until you commit/cancel the transaction.
I want all my clients to remain unchanged (since they are used in other contexts as well) where there is no transaction, all while keeping a single instance of the ViewService.

I tried using an injection token in the module of the app that has the transactions stuff like the problem is that this results in having 2 instances of the ViewService (one global and one for this module):

```
export const VIEW_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ViewService>('view-service');

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: VIEW_SERVICE, useClass: ViewService },
    { provide: ViewService, useClass: TransactionViewService },
  ],
 }
```

so my `TransactionViewService` becomes:

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionViewService {

    // add to pending if transaction. call inner viewService on commit

    constructor(
        @Inject(VIEW_SERVICE) private viewService: ViewService,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this or am I going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a dummy service that just fwds the calls and gets overridden in the module that uses transactions so both the `DummyViewService` and the `TransactionsViewService` need the `@Inject(VIEW_SERVICE)` to get the base view service:

```
export const VIEW_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ViewService>('view-service');

//root module:
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: VIEW_SERVICE, useClass: ViewService },
    { provide: ViewService, useClass: DummyViewService },
  ],
 }

//module that supports transactions:
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: ViewService, useClass: TransactionViewService },
  ],
 }
```